# Use task based on #{fileExtname} on VS Code tasks.json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

i have been trying to use a condition to check the current opened file extension name so i can use different tasks automatically, but without success.

This is the current tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "echoCommand": true,

    "tasks": 
    [
        {
            "taskName": "Build c++",
            "command": "",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": ["g++", "-o", "${fileBasenameNoExtension}", "${fileBasename}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

My objective is to make something like:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "echoCommand": true,

    if(#{fileExtname} == ".cpp")
    {
        "tasks": 
        [
            {
                "taskName": "Build",
                "command": "",
                "isBuildCommand": true,
                "args": ["g++", "-o", "${fileBasenameNoExtension}", "${fileBasename}"]
            }
        ]
    }

    if(#{fileExtname} == ".java")
    {
        "tasks": 
        [
            {
                "taskName": "Build",
                "command": "",
                "isBuildCommand": true,
                "args": ["javac", "${fileBasename}"]
            }
        ]
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that's possible. However, you can soon achieve this by [writing a small extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) - the upcoming 1.14.0 release will include an [API for generating tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/release-notes/v1_14.md#new-task-api). It would be fairly simple to generate different tasks based on[`window.activeTextEditor.document.languageId`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_window).

Comment: That's unfortunate, but I'm glad we will be able to do it soon. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: They've just released 1.14.0. :)

Comment: I love how fast VS Code is updated. Thanks for the insight! Now off I go to read the documentation...